# Physical intuition behind Green's theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I get what the theorem is saying. The circulation of the curve is equal to adding up the "microscopic" curls. But why? Why does adding up the "microscopic curls" give you the circulation? Could someone give me an explanation of it using a physical analogy? I.e. an object rotating in moving body of water?

Comment: The whole is the sum of the parts.

Comment: I think the Feynman lectures on physics have a good explanation of Green's theorem.  They are free online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'microscopic' curls cancel along all their shared boundaries, because they always go in opposite directions. The only thing you're left with is the curl along the 'macroscopic' exterior boundary.

You might also want to ask this question in Physics SE.

---

Added. See comment below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "cancel along their shared boundaries"?

Comment: I mean that if you look at two ajoining cells with a clockwise rotation, for example two cells next to each other, the anticlockwise rotation in the left cell is moving down along the common boundary, while the anticlockwise rotation in the right cell is moving up along that common boundary.

Comment: I've added a rough diagram illustrating this: there are cancellations in all the interior boundaries between cells, leaving only the circulation on the exterior boundary. Hope that helps qualitatively.

Comment: The diagram cleared things up immediately - thanks a lot Simon!